# Camera Calibrator Matlab

Tags: matlab, camera-calibration

I'm using the camera corrector application to correct a series of images that have barrel distortion using chessboards.
Following the steps below:

1.I attach the series of photos to be corrected with the different positions of the chessboard, without modifying the position of the camera.

2. I introduce the size of the different squares that make up the board. And frame that has a high distortion the image to process
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKWpp.jpg)
3. I perform the processing of the different photos and press the calibration button
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjckq.jpg)
4. Detect the different points of the chessboard
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od6hv.jpg)
5. And I hit the "show undistorted" button. To see the result of the correction.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3gab.jpg)

Apparently the image is corrected. But using a photo correction program, I observed that this is not the case, that there are errors in its correction.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKeSL.jpg)

it is observed that the upper right corner is not fully corrected. I have carried out the same procedure with a smaller number of photos, with a different location of the chessboard, etc. I am somewhat confused. What could I do to completely correct the image?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlpNS.jpg)

Comment: if you have trouble in the corners, you need more data in the corners. that's the downside of having to recognize _whole_ checkerboards.

Comment: For image correction I install the calibration panel (chessboard) in different positions (in the four corners, the center, etc). I install it in all existing positions to occupy the largest field of vision of the area to be corrected.

Comment: for radially symmetric distortions there's this function lensdistort() from https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37980-barrel-and-pincushion-lens-distortion-correction?s_tid=srchtitle_barrel%20distortion_1 that may be helpful to solve this quesiton. Would you please be so kind to post 2 images? an original and a distorted one? so reader can better assess your question and assist in supplying an answer?

Comment: In the formulation of the question there is a distorted image in section 3 and 4. And in section 5 and in the following paragraphs I show the "corrected" image. In the last paragraph I introduce reference lines to check if it is completely correct.